# SQLAlchemy many to many against same table with no hierarchy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I would like to build a relationship between instances of a single table in Sqlalchemy using the declarative method.

I have a table called Hex, which represent hexagons on a map. I would like a table called Link which links two hexes together. The backref "links" on each instance should return at most 6 links, meaning a unique constraint on the hex edge type. Additionally, I'm trying to use the association object so I can have methods on this link class.

So:
Given Hex A and Hex B
A -> B (A.links should contain a link to B)
B -> A (B.links should contain the **same** link object to A)

**My question**: 
What kind of relationship is this called? I've tried other methods but this example I've demonstrated doesn't have a parent child relationship.

Edit:

I tried this configuration:

```
class Link(Base, Record):
    __tablename__ = 'link'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    hex_a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('hex.id'), index=True)
    hex_a = relationship('Hex', backref=backref('links', lazy='dynamic'), foreign_keys='Link.hex_a_id')

    hex_b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('hex.id'), index=True)
    hex_b = relationship('Hex', backref=backref('links', lazy='dynamic'), foreign_keys='Link.hex_b_id')

    type = Column(PythonEnum(HexEdge, 'id'), nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('hex_a_id', 'hex_b_id', name='_link_uc'), )
```

and got this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'links' on relationship 'Link.hex_b': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Hex|hex'
```